# Play framework cannot provision MessagesAPI

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, guice

This afternoon I tried to run my play app and got a stack I have never seen before. It looks like it's having trouble loading the DefaultDessagesApi (which I inject into my controllers) but I'm not sure why? I didn't want to post my entire controller but here is the stack:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, @70ppffi4h: Configuration error in :23
  at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.<init>(Messages.scala:482)
  at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.class(Messages.scala:482)
  while locating play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi
  while locating play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
    for parameter 0 at controllers.WebApp.<init>(WebApp.scala:28)
  while locating controllers.WebApp
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:35)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
Caused by: @70ppffi4h: Configuration error in :23
    at play.api.i18n.Messages$MessagesParser.parse(Messages.scala:329)
    at play.api.i18n.Messages$.parse(Messages.scala:253)
    at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi$$anonfun$loadMessages$2.apply(Messages.scala:549)
    at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi$$anonfun$loadMessages$2.apply(Messages.scala:548)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
    at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.loadMessages(Messages.scala:548)
    at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.loadAllMessages(Messages.scala:557)
    at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.<init>(Messages.scala:490)
    at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi$$FastClassByGuice$$63166e8f.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:82)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:78)
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: Can you check your actual `conf/messages` file(s) don't contain any malformed values, e.g. something with a mismatched brace on a parameter placeholder? The exception is being thrown trying to parse them when instantiating the `MessagesApi` instance.

Comment: I can't find any errors in my conf files. The only thing that has changed recently was the addition of play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "en-US" ] but that had been working previously. Is there somewhere else this could be breaking besides the conf files?

Comment: Which version of Play are you using (I assume not actually 2.0)? And if you could post the contents of your messages.* files in a gist or somewhere  that might help...

Comment: That was it! I had deleted a two line entry and moved it causing the error. Thank you very much for your help!